# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, innerhtml

***im getting error in this code and what should ebe equal to inner html***

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
       {
          document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = `enter code here`;
       }
      };
            xhttp.open("GET","https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=London,uk&appid=2ed23a9e218c67041a6853dec1eb24da", true);
          xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine with a different endpoint, see below. That url requires a *valid* API key, maybe you aren't sending that in your request.

The server response has status 401 and the message:

```
{
  "cod":401,
   "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."
}
```

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
       {
          document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = `enter code here`;
       }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET","https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=London,uk&appid=2ed23a9e218c67041a6853dec1eb24da", true);
          xhttp.send();
```

```html
<div id="id">

</div>
```

Comment: 2ed23a9e218c67041a6853dec1eb24da thhis is the api key

Comment: hey now i have checked its now valid but all i get is this.... Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=London,uk&appid=2ed23a9e218c67041a6853dec1eb24da:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: try changing `weatherq` to `weather?q` - GET query strings must start with ?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: weather is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange...at line 17 still dont know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

HTML has not loaded yet

Either use an onload event or place the script at the end of body

```
  <body>
    <div>
      <span>The current weather in London is: </span><span id="id"></span>
    </div>
    <script>
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = `enter code here`;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open(
        "GET",
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=London,uk&appid=2ed23a9e218c67041a6853dec1eb24da",
        true
      );
      xhttp.send();
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: can you guide me?

Comment: I have added the code in my above answer, of course you still need a valid api key for openweathermap to send you the desired response

You can register and add the api key to your querystring as shown here
https://openweathermap.org/appid